# Are there any cases where LINQ's .Where() will be faster than O(N)?

Tags: linq, performance, big-o

Think the title describes my thoughts pretty well :)

I've seen a lot of people lately that swear to LINQ, and while I also believe it's awesome, I also think you shouldn't be confused about the fact that on most (all?) IEnumerable types, it's performance is not that great. Am I wrong in thinking this? Especially queries where you nest Where()'s on large datasets?

Sorry if this question is a bit vague, I just want to confirm my thoughts in that you should be "cautious" when using LINQ.

[EDIT] Just to clarify - I'm thinking in terms of Linq to Objects here :)

Comment: I think being cautious with LINQ is a good idea. There are some subtle things that can bite you hard if you are not aware of it, like deferred execution and likewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a project that promises to introduce indexing for LINQ2Objects. This should deliver better asymptotic behavior: http://i4o.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

It  depends on the provider.  For Linq to Objects, it's going to be O(n), but for Linq to SQL or Entities it might ultimately use indices to beat that.  For Objects, if you need the functionality of Where, you're probably going to need O(n) anyway.  Linq *will* almost certainly have a bigger constant, largely due to the function calls.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, meant Linq to objects here. I was thinking if there's an IEnumerable implementation here that somehow can beat O(N) - But I guess there aren't :)

Comment: Well, the Where for `IEnumerable` objects is `Enumerable.Where`, so there's really only one implementation.  Even if it wanted to special case, I don't see how it could beat O(n).

Comment: AFAIK, IEnumerable only defines GetEnumerator(), which in turn only exposes GetNext() and Reset(). .Where is an extension method, which I don't know if anyone built in datatype cares to override. My guess is that .Where is just a foreach in disguise? :)

Comment: Yes, [Mono's](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs#l3002) at least is just a foreach in an iterator-generator.

Comment: Spent a little time in Reflector, and it seems like .Any, .Single, .All, and the likes are implemented in the straightforward way you'd assume. Couldn't find the logic for .Where though :S

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are using it and to what you compare.

I've seen many implementations using `foreache`s which would have been much faster with linq. Eg. because they forget to break or because they return too many items. The trick is that the lambda expressions are executed when the item is actually used. When you have `First` at the end, it could end up it just one single call.

So when you chain `Where`s, if an item does not pass the first condition, it will also not be tested for the second condition. it's similar to the `&&` operator, which does not evaluate the condition on the right side if the first is not met.

You could say it's always O(N). But N is not the number of items in the source, but the minimal number of items required to create the target set. That's a pretty good optimization IMHO.

Comment: Indeed, chaining `.First()` on the end of a `.Where()` will be less than O(N) as long as something matches that isn't the last element...